# Why does my triangle does not shown correctly?

Tags: python, opengl, matrix

**Good evening,**

I've followed this tutorial [learnopengl.com](http://learnopengl.com/#!In-Practice/2D-Game/Rendering-Sprites) with python instead of c++. Everything seems to work but my triangle doesn't show up correctly.

I checked every single line if I missed something more than twice but I cant find the issue.

[SpriteRenderer](http://pastie.org/private/d2qfz1appqas9l5v7x2rsw) | [Shader](http://pastie.org/private/ewruzvzmdqy12eqihephza) | [ResourceManager](http://pastie.org/private/6gbbvujrhaebr0snxg4cw) | [Program](http://pastie.org/private/hhv8x258lohwtvxdjhhrdg) | [Game](http://pastie.org/private/hg6b0sxtvfl4rkoballtoq) (change the path inside Game to the shaders)

**EDIT**

Okay well now I can see my triangle, when I change

- **rotation to 0**
- **position** ***AND*** **size** to the same size like **200, 200**
- and instead of **transform.ortho(0., SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0, -1, 1)** to ***transform.ortho(0., SCREEN_WIDTH, 0, SCREEN_HEIGHT, -1, 1)***
- using the **same** **model matrix (SpriteRenderer) down below**

[image]

**Important Snippets**

orth matrix (Game)

```
array([[ 0.0025    ,  0.        ,  0.        , -1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.00333333,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        , -1.        , -0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ]], dtype=float32)
```

model matrix (SpriteRenderer)

```
T = glm.translation_matrix([position[0],position[1],0])
# bewegt den den pivot zum mittelpunkt
Tcenter = glm.translation_matrix([0.5 * size[0], 0.5 * size[1], 0])
R = glm.rotation_matrix(rotate, [0,0,1])
# bewegt den pivot wieder zurueck
Tback = glm.translation_matrix([-0.5 * size[0], -0.5 * size[1], 0])
# scaliert den koerper
S = glm.compose_matrix(scale = [size[0],size[1],1])

model = glm.concatenate_matrices(T, Tcenter, R, Tback, S)

self._shader.setMatrix4("model", model)
self._shader.setVector("customColor", color)

gl.glBindVertexArray(self._vao);
gl.glDrawArrays(gl.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)
gl.glBindVertexArray(0)
```

VAO VBO (SpriteRenderer)

```
vertexBufferData = np.array(([-1, -1],
                             [ 1, -1],
                             [ 0,  1]),
                             dtype='float32')

# ----- VBO ------

# Request a buffer slot from GPU
VBO = gl.glGenBuffers(1)
# Make this buffer the default one
gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO)
# Upload data
gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferData.nbytes ,vertexBufferData, gl.GL_STATIC_DRAW)

# ------ VAO ------

# Aktivieren des Vertex Array mit der ID
gl.glBindVertexArray(self._vao)
gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.GL_FLOAT, False, 0, c_void_p(0))
#len(vertexBufferData), gl.GL_FLOAT, gl.GL_FALSE,4*4, c_void_p(0))

# unbind das aktuelle vertex objekt VAO und VBO
#gl.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0)
gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
gl.glBindVertexArray(0)
```

**fragmentshader**:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 color;

uniform vec3 customColor;

void main()
{
    color = vec4(customColor, 1.0);
}
```

**vertexshader**

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec2 position;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * model * vec4(position.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: It's probably correct.  How have you computed your orthographic matrix?

Comment: projection = transform.ortho(0., self.width, self.height, 0., -1., 1.) -> Inside of Game ... Where width = 800, height = 600. But I had to transpose the Matrix before I finnaly passed it to OpenGL. So now -1 and 1 are on the top right hand corner. This is the transform script http://www.labri.fr/perso/nrougier/teaching/opengl/scripts/transforms.py